# Change Content with ButtonClick, ContentControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contentcontrol

I made example where I change Content with ComboBoxMenu:

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource InsideBorders}">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=ComboBoxMenu, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
</Border>
```

But how do it the same thing for button? There I have no "SelectedItem" property.

I have two buttons with which I will change Content. Buttons are on different places not in one DockPanel or similar, so DataTemplate I think is not possible. Or?

Comment: I like to use TabControl but I didnt suggest the design :)
I use this example [link](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/), change it. I made two different ItemsControls with same ItemTemplate. It is a little bit amateur coding, but it is a solution :) So now I can have two buttons on different places and change same content.

Answer (score 1):

In case of `ComboBox` you can set its `ItemsSource` but in case of button you need to associate button with object, based on which `ContentControl` adjusts its view. My suggestion is to create list of possible values and assign each one to associated button. 
 
**C#:**

```
enum ContentControlViewModel
{
    MainViewModel,
    SearchViewModel
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button Tag="{x:Static local:ContentControlViewModel.MainViewModel}"/>
```

Then create style for all buttons which are supposed to change `ContentControl`'s view.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
     <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SetContentControlViewModel}"/>
     <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag}"/>
</Style>
```

Then in `SetContentControlViewModel` command all you need to do is to assign value to `CurrentViewModel` property, based on parameter. Your `ContentControl` binds to `CurrentViewModel` and adjusts view.

```
private object _currentViewModel;

public object CurrentViewModel
{
     get { return _currentViewModel; }
     set
     {
         _currentViewModel = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
     }
}

public void SetViewModel(ContentControlViewModel viewModel)
{
     switch (viewModel)
     {
          case ContentControlViewModel.MainViewModel:
          CurrentViewModel = new MainViewModel();
          break;
     }
}
```